# Given a system, how to decide whether a closed orbit is homoclinic, not periodic, solely based on its phase portrait?

Tags: phase-space, stability, non-linear-systems, complex-systems

Background and definitions:

- A system is conservative if it has at least one conserved quantity.
- In a phase portrait of a nonlinear conservative system, trajectories that start and end at the same fixed point are homoclinic. (A homoclinic orbit is not periodic because it takes infinite time so that the trajectory reach the fixed point after leaving it.)

---

Assume that we have the phase portrait associated with a system whose energy conservation is not known. If we knew the system were conservative, closed orbits in its phase portrait were homoclinic. But without this assumption, (since phase portrait does not convey information about time) how can one decide whether a closed orbit is periodic or homoclinic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One misconception here is to assume that

> If we knew the system were conservative, closed orbits in its phase portrait were homoclinic.

Actually a typical conservative system's closed orbits are almost always quasiperiodic or periodic. For instance, the only homoclinic point in the phase portrait below is the x-shaped crossing at the origin:

[image]

All the other curves are periodic orbits. ([Source](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DuffingDifferentialEquation.html) of the image.)

FWIW, homoclinic orbits tend to be non-smooth at the periodic point, since it sits at the transversal [intersection](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HomoclinicPoint.html) of invariant manifolds.